# VB arraylist accessing in another class

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

I'm writing a POS application for a course. I'm having trouble accessing itemList of type ArrayList in a different class. Below is my code of the two classes. Is it possible to access an arrayList in another class (i.e. inside `Transaction`)?

```
Public Class Item

    'Declares item variables
    Public itemName As String
    Public itemPrice As Decimal
    Public itemQty As Integer
    Public itemSku As Long
    Public itemList As New ArrayList
    Public newItem As Item


    'Method passes details of item
    Public Sub AddItem(itemSku, itemName, itemPrice, itemQty)
        itemSku = newItem.itemSku
        itemName = newItem.itemName
        itemPrice = newItem.itemPrice
        itemQty = newItem.itemQty
        itemList.Add(newItem) 'adds newItem to arrayList of items itemList
    End Sub


End Class


Public Class Transaction
    Dim subtotal As Decimal
    Dim tax As Decimal
    Dim total As Decimal
    Dim paymentType As String

    Public Function calculateBalance()
        For count As Integer = 0 To itemList.Count 'TRYING TO ACCESS ARRAYLIST HERE

        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not indicating an actual instance of class `Item` whose `itemList` should be used. Change the function to:

```
Public Function calculateBalance(myItem As Item)
    For count As Integer = 0 To myItem.itemList.Count 'TRYING TO ACCESS ARRAYLIST HERE

    Next
End Function
```

Comment: In order for this to work do I need to generate a field of type item?

Comment: Yep, you need to instantiate an `Item` object somewhere else, then pass it to the function. As an alternative, you could pass just the `itemList` to the function if the rest of the `Item` isn't used by the function. It all depends on what exactly you're trying to do with your program.